# Creating Json file from Excel and want to pass null when cell is blank but having difficulty finding the right syntax

Tags: excel, vba

Script is working great and saves json file, but if table cells are blank they are eliminated from the json output.  Would love some assistance to solve.

```
`Private Sub SaveAsJSON_Click()
 
 Set ObjectProperties = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 
 For Each c In ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Cells
    ObjectProperties.Add c.Column, c.Value

Next

Dim CollectionToJson As New Collection

For Each r In ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows
    Set jsonObject = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each c In r.Range.Cells
        jsonObject.Add ObjectProperties(c.Column), c.Value
    
    Next
    
    CollectionToJson.Add jsonObject

    
Next
 
 fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="JSON Files (*.json), *.json")
 
 If fileSaveName <> False Then
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    Open fileSaveName For Output As fileNumber
        Print #fileNumber, JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(CollectionToJson, Whitespace:=2)
        Close fileNumber

End If
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Dim v As Variant
'...
'...
v = c.Value 
jsonObject.Add ObjectProperties(c.Column), IIf(Len(v) > 0, v, Null)
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Col001": "blah",
    "Col002": null,
    "Col003": 44,
    "Col004": "blah",
    "Col005": "blah",
    "Col006": 66,
    "Col007": "blah"
  },
  {
    "Col001": "blah",
    "Col002": "blah",
    "Col003": 67,
    "Col004": "blah",
    "Col005": "blah",
    "Col006": null,
    "Col007": "blah"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you I am now seeing all columns in the results but all text values are converted to numbers.  Would like to see all values and null vs 0 in the blank fields. I have tested a couple of changes but still not working.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add a sample row of data, and what you're seeing in your json vs. what you want/expect?  Did you Dim v as Variant?

Comment: This is the result post change recommended

{
    "  Name": 6,
    "  Abrev": 4,
    "  AlternateNameZHCN": 0,
    "  AlternateNameZHTW": 0,

Looking for: 

{
  "Name": "Activities\/Recreation",
  "Abrev": "RECR",
  "AlternateNameZHCN": null,
  "AlternateNameZHTW": null,

Comment: Sorry I just noticed a copy/paste error in my posted code.  `v = c.Value` not `v = Len(c.Value)`

Comment: Excellent Tim!  Worked like a charm!  Sincerely appreciate the assist!